# Interrupt busy loop in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a simple busy loop in my Node.js code that has turned out to take several seconds to complete. During this time I need to perform some I/O operations, which currently are queued and all executed after the loop instead of "parallel" with the loop. I know that Node doesn't do parallel execution, so I'm looking for some way to interrupt the loop to allow Node to do other stuff.

I have tried implementing the loop with async, but that resulted in exceeding the call stack (*i* easily goes up to 2,000,000).

```
while(i < length){
    if(something) sendWebSocketMessage();
    //Do stuff with i
    i++;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to write your loop like this:

```
(function step(){
     doSomething();
     if (length--) setImmediate(step);
})();
```

This way other events coming in between would be handled. If your loop is long because of a big number of iterations (vs because of long steps), you could have a partial looping in place of `doSomething()`.

If you want to slow down your loop, in order to let more time to other tasks, you could also use `setTimeout` with a non null timeout:

```
(function step(){
     doSomething();
     if (length--) setTimeout(step, 5);
})();
```